# Get Custom Taxonomy Name With Term ID

Tags: wordpress

How can i get the name or slug of **custom taxonomy** of my Custom Post Type from **term id** that it belongs?

If **Term1** is my term name that belongs under **TaxName** Custom Taxonomy then i need to know the slug or name of **TaxName** with term id of **Term1** that i have.

Answer (score -1):

There's a function to get custom taxonomy name: 
`<?php get_term_by( $field, $value, $taxonomy, $output, $filter ) ?>`

Here's the complete reference : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by

Comment: What is taxonomy in mycase?

Comment: If i know the termid ie. suppose **tid**. How am i supppose to get the taxonomy name **TaxName** with that?